Facebook Api Post page insights, Facebook video upload
I use facebook graph api in my app and I faced some issues I cannot crack for a while. Unfortunately their documentation is not always clear, so I would appreciate any tips on my questions. My app is build in Next.js, but I don't think language matters here.
1.Upload video trouble.
I follow this documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing
Publish video on the page takes three steps.
1.1 Start an upload session. I use here my business app Id and my test user account for user access token
 curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/<APP_ID>/uploads
 ?file_name=<FILE_NAME>
 &file_length=<FILE_LENGTH>
 &file_type=<FILE_TYPE>
 &access_token=<USER_ACCESS_TOKEN>"

I get successfull return
{
  "id": "upload:<UPLOAD_SESSION_ID>"
}

1.2. Start upload session. Same user token as in the first call and upload session Id which I received in the first response. Currently I test in Postman, so no issues yet converting video file, just file attached type video/mp4.
 curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/upload:<UPLOAD_SESSION_ID>"
  --header "Authorization: OAuth <USER_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
  --header "file_offset: 0"
  --data-binary @<FILE_NAME>

Success. Receive file handle response
{
   "h": "2:c2FtcGxl..."
}

1.3. Publish video. And here is an error
 curl -X POST \
  "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v20.0/<PAGE_ID>/videos" \
  -F "access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  -F "title=<VIDEO_TITLE>" \
  -F "description=<VIDEO_DESCRIPTION>" \ 
  -F "fbuploader_video_file_chunk=<UPLOADED_FILE_HANDLE>"

Page Id I use Page from my test user account, page token from this page. Handle - response from previous step. It end up in response:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Using file handle created for another user",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "AOF82skhP9OWC_yFlh_ka4q"
   }
 }

Question? For whom did they create a handle?? Which another user? I use page credentials which belong to the user, whom user_token I used in the first steps. I follow all official documentation with headers, I insert user token in the header in the second step, as required, but I always end up with this error. Any ideas what potentially can go wrong?
2.Post Page insights for analytics.
I get analytics for page following this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v20.0/insights
For example call
  GET v20.0/{Page_Id}/insights?metric=page_post_engagements,page_daily_follows&period=week&since=01.09.2024&untill=30.09.2024

There are three options for most of metrics - day, week and days_28. What is not clear for me, its's how to combine it with 'since' and 'untill'? I have an interactive page, where user can dynamically select 'period', 'since' and 'untill with datePicker, It always shows different data and I'm not sure what exactly I display..
for the call
 page_id/insights?metric=page_post_engagements&since=01.09.2024

I will receive data for day, week, and day_28, per day since selected date till today. But data for the same day in each of there three sections will differ. What does this data represent?
Example response:
 "name": "page_post_engagements",
  "period": "day",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-02T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-03T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-04T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-05T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 9,
      "end_time": "2024-09-06T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 4,
      "end_time": "2024-09-07T07:00:00+0000"
    },
},
{
  "name": "page_post_engagements",
  "period": "week",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-02T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-03T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-04T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "end_time": "2024-09-05T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 9,
      "end_time": "2024-09-06T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 13,
      "end_time": "2024-09-07T07:00:00+0000"
    },
},
{
  "name": "page_post_engagements",
  "period": "days_28",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 5,
      "end_time": "2024-09-02T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 5,
      "end_time": "2024-09-03T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 5,
      "end_time": "2024-09-04T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 5,
      "end_time": "2024-09-05T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 14,
      "end_time": "2024-09-06T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 18,
      "end_time": "2024-09-07T07:00:00+0000"
    },

Can someone explain me please? If I want, for example, display : "Your page activity this week increased/dropped for 15% compare to last week", how do I need to set my search params?
Thanks everyone for any ideas
